# Are Google Cloud Storage files indexed in search?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

If I upload some files into a Google Cloud Storage bucket and made them public does Google index them in search results?

Answer (score 2):

Google's search index is independent of Google Cloud Storage (GCS). Making a file public in GCS does not automatically index it in Google's search results.

So, public files in GCS will not automatically be indexed by Google.

Comment: Hi - I understand it will not be indexed automatically. But will it be eventually indexed after a period of time? Or would I need to submit the link for indexing? Or it's even possible to index that link?

Comment: I hit the enter button before completing my answer. Edited now.

Comment: You will have to submit it for it to be get indexed. It will never index it automatically.

Comment: It's still eligible for indexing, if you submit it yourself or if discovered by normal crawling.